# holomorphic extension of real valued function with bounded derivatives on [0,1]

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

I have encountered the following question: 
 let $f \in C^\infty([0,1])$. Assume that there exists some constant number $C>0$, such that for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f^{(n)}| \leq C^{n+1}\cdot n!$$
prove that there exists some domain $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ s.t $[0,1] \subseteq G$, and a function $g$ holomorphic in $G$, such that $g_{|[0,1]}\equiv f$


I've got lost trying to solve this one. I tried to solve for $f$ which is a polynomial and to use Berenstein's theorem, but couldn't solve this case either. Anyone?

Comment: Use Taylor's Theorem to show the Taylor series converges to $f$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich
Thank you!
I have managed to show it is true, but I do not understand, why does it mean that there exists such domain G?